# camel snmp can't resive snmpversion=3 info

Tags: apache-camel, snmp

When I use came-snmp resive snmp info which version is 3, it can't go to the process method.

```
@Component
public class SnmpCollect extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("snmp:0.0.0.0:162?protocol=udp&type=TRAP&snmpVersion=3&securityName=test").process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        }
    }
}
```

Camel xml config:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="snmpCollect"/>
</camelContext>
```

But when the snmp info which version is 1 or 2 is coming, it can go to the process method.

What's wrong with it, and how to make it work for "snmpVersion=3" info?

Camel Version is 2.20.1

Comment: When I use the TrapTest where is on the camel-snmp github “https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-snmp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/snmp/TrapTest.java”，it‘s ok.But when I change the snmpVersion to SnmpConstants.version3,it's also error.

Comment: You are having problems when using SNMP version 3, that's it? And version 1 and 2 are working fine? Could you post the error you are facing? Or aren't you having any errors, just the `Process` method isn't working?

Comment: The Process method isn't working when the SNMPV3's info is coming.So there no any errors.I think this params isn't work.when I set it value to 9 or any other number,version 1 and 2 are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your question by providing some info based in what I've found.

Seems that he requirements and interfaces from v1 and v2 version differ from v3, so it doesn't like to work just updating the version. The mainly difference, from what I've seen, is that you need to provide a [security model to v3](http://www.snmp.com/products/techinfo/secmodels.shtml). I saw that you are passing it via parameters, but have you got the chance to check the security requirements?

> When I use the TrapTest where is on the camel-snmp github “github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-snmp/s‌​rc/…”，it‘s ok.But when I change the snmpVersion to SnmpConstants.version3,it's also error

That's because the interface changed and the test should rely on `ScopedPDU` model instead of the base class `PDU`. Also the security model isn't set up in this test:

`org.snmp4j.MessageException: Message processing model 3 returned error: Unsupported security model`

Unfortunately there isn't any example using `camel-snmp` with v3, but you could take a look into [this example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/snmp4j/snmpv3-set-example-using-snmp4j/) using the inner component `snmp4j`.